# SQL Server 2014 - How to get list of members from window group account

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a user in database A, this user is a role account, something like 'DIR\XXXX' which i used this role account to control who can access to database A. Now my question is how can get a list of members that assigned to this role account ? I tried by below method but failed

```
EXEC xp_logininfo 'DIR\Management_Accountant_Group', 'members'
```

Here the error message

```
Msg 15404, Level 16, State 4, Procedure xp_logininfo, Line 43
Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'DIR\Management_Accountant_Group', error code 0x6ba.
```

Comment: Check this link on how to do it via powershell: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/powershell/137871/

Comment: Is there a way to get this is sql server without go thru powershell ?

Comment: Not that I know of.